# Sending *.exe by changing extension failed

Tags: email, file-extension, attachments, restrictions

I know you can send **.exe** through email by changing their extension. I've been using this often. But strange thing happen when I tried to send this specific ".exe" file. It failed!!

It's this compressor, **uharc.exe**. Full app can be downloaded [from here](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~sag47/uharc/). I just need the **uharc.exe** that you can find in the bin folder.

Actually, failure didn't occure at gmail (I'm using it). But the recipient has rejected it (the recipient is in some private network). But how can the recipient identify that particular file only! Well, i haven't tried sending **exe**'s before, but I've sent **jar** files which were rejected if I send without changing the extension..

Can anyone explain how's this happening. Is there any solution for this...(please note that the recipient's machine has strictly limited access. Can't download, install, even web surfing is much limited.. and that's why I'm doing this..)

---

This is what gmail said about the failure..

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     ***@***.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain. We recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause of this error. The error that the other server returned was: 550 550 5.7.1 Error: content rejected (state 17).

----- Original message -----

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
        h=mime-version:date:message-id:subject:from:to:content-type;
        bh=QEk6/JzSwEYG+xPfJ5u4hmg00M3ANp+9zuGfwUNsWJ4=;
        b=DXcn1PO//71206sw0/3WLsuOPDYQ1lRimDhs57WARqa2mzsli76O9AExXwvuPBP6HH
         K47myiF169lwluDToZvaNYdLilNHvny6JD/JcIWthnILtnTDMjjzQf4WXXO9QFh06o/G
         bcUHHDPXkkN+4777s7VuM1awRpt4rzrE1d2vRialE++fEn5LSAboNh8g7yZ9zvlykyID
         V6pLMfVXHWaQdTdhgFDi/bUlVoJkqscGA1YVtHgyRY+vEJPzTgf60LHYV/zAtaVAeWQa
         O4UOM5u4lD8c1woDJywU1n6JpO99TI1sjcalcfORbF/mniDfcz+16HvxFwUG1AecEOxI
         6bwg==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.49.104.65 with SMTP id gc1mr1327542qeb.22.1351846482769; Fri,
 02 Nov 2012 01:54:42 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.49.107.231 with HTTP; Fri, 2 Nov 2012 01:54:42 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Fri, 2 Nov 2012 14:24:42 +0530
Message-ID: <CAHaGyLDEc12LTiEhJxfCO64QQMb6CroKrY-8nU2nWEEBQwEaJA@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: JPEG
From: Sumudu Lansakara <*myemail*@gmail.com>
To: *** *** <***@***.com>
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=047d7b5dbd946575d304cd7f495f
```

---

**EDIT**

I found that i can't sent any ***.exe** by this method. Recipient always reject them. Hope there'll be some solution!! (without using any third party app..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution would be to **zip the exe file** and **encrypt it** by locking it with a **password**. This should keep most spam/virus prevention systems from making out that it contains a .exe file

Answer (score 1):

Rejecting messages with a binary executable attachment, whether it has an .exe extension or not, is a spam/virus prevention measure.

ZIP (or use some other compression algorithm) the .exe before you send it. Except for extremely common document file types, you should do this when sending email attachments anyway.

Comment: Sending zip (even .7z) also fails. Tried changing the extension of the compressed file. It still fail. Any workaround??

Comment: That's true, though some spam filters can read ZIP and check them out for binary data too. Email might not be the best transfer method here.

Comment: @Xyon So what are you suggesting? But as I said, my recipient side machine is strictly limited. Can't download any file (except email attachments).

Comment: @Anubis Your particular restrictions make it difficult to contemplate any method of getting your file transferred. Why so restrictive?

Comment: I can contact IT department and copy the file easily. But I like to do it this way.. more fun!!

Comment: @Xyon Well, about **why so restrictive**. I dunno! really dunno. Yep that really sucks. But I'm just a trainee here. Don't have rights to argue with them..As I told, I can get this done. But just need to know whether this can be achieved this way (through emails). Isn't there any inbuilt encryption methods (in windows XP and later..) etc.. that can be used to encrypt the content??

Comment: Open the .exe in a hex editor and save the code as plaintext, perhaps in multiple chunks. Then have your recipient stitch it back together on the other side.

Comment: Fair enough, I can understand that. Your problem is going to be compressing / encrypting the file in such a way that it masks the binary nature of it, but doesn't look suspicious to the spamfilter. Ironically you'd probably get away with it if you used uharc compression. The only native encryption I know of in XP is the NTFS encryption provided by the filesystem, which won't help you much. In fact I think only zip is built-in compression, too. You could always hex-dump the thing to plain text and convert it back on the other side, maybe...?

Comment: @NReilingh Ok, then can I rebuild it in the other side without the help of any hex editor?

Comment: @Xyon **"hex-dump the thing to plain text and convert it back on the other side"** can I do it manually?? without any hex editor??

Comment: have you tried ZIP **with a password**? if that encrypts, the antispam probably cant catch it.

Comment: @KarthikT Good idea, I'll try!

Comment: @KarthikT Sorry for the delay.. It worked!! thanks..

Comment: @KarthikT can you post it as an answer..

Answer (score 0):

Did you hit the file size limit supported by their email account? Are you sure its the right email? Are you spamming the guys email box with viri and they blocked you?

This a generic rejection notice and I suspect it has nothing to do with the changing of the extension method failing.

Comment: Please see the comments to above first answer. Karthi T's method worked. Thanks anyway!