# Trying to attach an excel spreadsheet to an email - says the attachment has a virus and to remove

Tags: microsoft-excel, attachments

I am trying to send an Excel spreadsheet by Yahoo! mail. When I try and attach it, it says there is a virus detected and to remove the attachment (I have also tried to attach it in a zip file). I have done a virus sweep on my PC, and it is totally clear. Any ideas? I need to send this attachment.

Comment: Does the spreadsheet contain any macros which may be detected as viruses? What version of Excel did you use to create the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem as in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/498275/sending-exe-by-changing-extension-failed/502607#502607) in such cases you can **zip with a password** and send that. Unless your client blocks even zip files